# ASP.NET Web API binding model properties to different request properties

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to write a custom model binder that can bind a property decorated with an attribute to a differently-named request property e.g.

#### JSON request

```
{
    "app": "acme"
}
```

#### Request model (excerpt)

```
[Alias("app")]
public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
```

... should result in `ApplicationName` being populated with the value 'acme'. I'm getting stuck writing the custom model binder for this:

#### Model binder

```
public BindToAliasModelBinder : IModelBinder {
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        ...
    }
}
```

#### Model binder provider

```
public class BindFromAliasModelBinderProvider : ModelBinderProvider {
    public override IModelBinder GetBinder(HttpConfiguration configuration, Type modelType) {
        return new BindFromAliasModelBinder();
    }
}
```

I've registered the provider globally and the binder is being hit as expected. I'm at a loss for what to do next - how do I iterate through the request values and conditionally bind based on the presence of the attribute?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is aliasing, you can use `JsonPropertyAttribute`, something like `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "app")]` on the property.

Comment: I've tried this, unfortunately it doesn't appear to work for binding. I've also the `DataMember` attribute with no luck.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution. I wast to use short names in the actual json but have meaningful variable name for debugging